# Unloading content in div that was place by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have 4 buttons on my page that load different partial view via ajax in asp.net mvc.  My buttons look like this

```
<button class="btn btn-thinkware btn-responsive aca-button" data-url='@Url.Action("Dashboard","Benefits")'>
<i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</button>
<button class="btn btn-thinkware aca-button" data-url='@Url.Action("HoursDetail","Benefits")'>
<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Hours Detail</button>
```

and my ajax looks like this.

```
$('.aca-button').on("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        var $dashboard = $('#partialDiv'),
            url = $(this).data('url');

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $dashboard.replaceWith(data);
        });
    });
```

I've tried using `$('#partialDiv').html("")` but that didn't unload on click.  Basically everytime I click a the different button I have to unload the div and reload the new partial.

Comment: Why not use $('#partialDiv').empty() here is helpful link https://api.jquery.com/empty

Comment: When I put that inside my click it doesn't seem to do anything. The first ajax call into my div stays loaded.

Comment: Make sure you get response data successfully with out any error.

Comment: `replaceWith` totally replaces the element with the new content. You shouldn't need to unload anything.

Comment: Does `data` contain the `partialDiv` DIV? If not, you should be using `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar that did it